# Help with computer without mouse

Tags: mac

I have a Mac computer I'm not sure exactly what type and it's not updated. All I have is one of the magic mouses or whatever and it won't connect without updating. In order to update I need to hit agree but I can click on it without a mouse. What do I do to hit agree and update it? (I have a keyboard)

Comment: Does tabbing do anything?

Comment: Um idk I'm an idiot with computers. HAHAHA

Comment: (By tabbing I mean pressing the `tab` key on the top left of your keyboard).

Comment: Sorry I'm kinda stupid @ruddfawcett    Ha!

Comment: Yeah no It's not doing anything

Comment: Did you check the battery in your Magic Mouse?  Is it turned on?

Comment: Yeah I followed exactly what the directions said but then it said I have to update it and now I'm stuck cause I can't hit the update button. 

Comment: Try hitting the enter key when it asks you to agree. Also does your mac have a trackpad?

Answer (score 3):

Connect a USB mouse and you should be able to get online and accept any updates.

Comment: This is the easiest way IMO (if you have a USB mouse, of course).

Comment: Yeah I poked for one but can't find one.

Comment: Looked*    God I can't type either

Answer (score 0):

Try to access the Mac remotely. Better Touch Tool has an iPhone/iPad app that will let you control the mouse (a few dollars), or TeamViewer or another VNC client will let you control and see your Mac on a phone or other computer (free).

No guarantees you can install these without using the mouse, though.